# SelectListItem is empty, if statement inside method shows it to be filled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**error message:**
http://prntscr.com/qtlodf

**method:**

```
    public IActionResult GroepsResultaten(int vakId, int groepId)
    {

        var studentenLijst = _context.Student.Join(_context.StudentGroep,
           s => s.Id,
           sg => sg.StudentId,
           (s, sg) => new { Student = s, StudentGroep = sg })
           .Where(x => x.StudentGroep.GroepId == groepId)
           .Select(x => x.Student);

        ViewBag.Studenten = new SelectList(studentenLijst, "Id", "Naam");
        return View();
    }
```

I've also tried this:

```
        public IActionResult GroepsResultaten(int vakId, int groepId)
        {

            var studentInfo = _context.Student
                .Select(s =>
                new
                {
                    s.Id,
                    Naam = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Tussenvoegsel)
                    ? s.Voornaam + " " + s.Achternaam + " - " + s.Studentnummer
                    : s.Voornaam + " " + s.Tussenvoegsel + " " + s.Achternaam + " - " + s.Studentnummer,
                    forStudent = s.Studentnummer + "-" + s.Achternaam
                });

            ViewBag.Studenten = new SelectList(studentInfo, "Id", "Naam");
            return View();
        }
```

I'm a bit stuck at this. I want to return multiple input fields (I'm just testing with selectlist at the moment) for all students of group x, from there on I want to be able to grade students for the subject that's included in the view using get method. Because English isn't my first language I've included two screenshots to clarify what I mean.

**clarification of what I want to achieve:**

*group view*: http://prntscr.com/qtlrqd

*wireframe of method view:* http://prntscr.com/qtlswn

**models:**

```
 public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Voornaam { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Achternaam { get; set; }
        public string Tussenvoegsel { get; set; }
        public string Studentnummer { get; set; }

        public List<Resultaat> Resultaten { get; set; }
        public List<StudentGroep> Groepen { get; set; }
    }

 public class Groep
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Naam { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Groepscode { get; set; }

        public List<GroepVak> Vakken { get; set; }
        public List<StudentGroep> Studenten { get; set; }
    }

public class StudentGroep
    {
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public Groep Groep { get; set; }
        public int GroepId { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope I've included enough information, I'm available on discord too if that makes it easier.

Comment: can you share your html code for select tag?

Comment: Please do not link to screenshots of code or error messages. If the link breaks your post will be not useful to people looking at anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is what the **SelectList** class returns. Because view side results that **ViewBag.Studenten** is null.

Also, you must make sure that the database query returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewData resulted in what I want, from here on I can hopefully figure out how to use it for posting grades for each student.

**Method:**

```
        public IActionResult GroepsResultaten(int vakId, int groepId)
    {

        var studentenLijst = _context.Student.Join(_context.StudentGroep,
           s => s.Id,
           sg => sg.StudentId,
           (s, sg) => new { Student = s, StudentGroep = sg })
           .Where(x => x.StudentGroep.GroepId == groepId)
           .Select(x => x.Student)
           .ToList();

        if (groepId >= 1)
        {
            ViewData["Studenten"] = studentenLijst.ToList();
        }
        //ViewBag.Studenten = new SelectList(studentenLijst, "Id", "Naam");
        return View();
    }
```

**View:**

```
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Studenten)
            {
                @item.Voornaam;
                <input type="number" />
            }
```